# Getting a script to start after gdm3 starts but BEFORE login

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to get a script to run **after** gdm3 starts but **before** a user logs in.  Reason is the script needs an active monitor, but if there's a power outage, I want the system to boot back to functional when power is restored.

I've tried various iterations based on other answers, but none of them seem to be performing the way I need it to.  I'm also trying to contain this in my custom systemd service definition and not touch any other service definitions, if possible.  Here's my current (not working) iteration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Testing
After=network.target network-online.target gdm3.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
Group=root

GuessMainPID=no
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/test.sh
Restart=never

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reboot -> Nothing.  After I login -> Nothing.  I can manually start it and it is enabled.  I reloaded the daemon after any edits and still nothing.

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Answer (score 0):

The logs were confusing because it looked like the script was triggering but nothing actually happened.  I figured it out based on the logs and quite a bit of Googling.

Looks like gdm has 2 X sessions; 1 pre-login and another post-login.  When I set my DISPLAY in the lines of the script along with Xauthority, I had the DISPLAY correct, but the Xauthority was the one that was post-login.  I just needed to SSH in before loging in, do `ps a | grep X` to find the proper Xauthority (which is the only one at this point since I haven't logged in through gdm), change the script with the correct Xauthority, reboot, and seems to be good now.